# динамический массив с++

Tags: c++

Задача написать функцию на С++,переводящую число X из 10 системы счисления в 3.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int a,x,k,x1,t;
int perefod(int x)
{   cin >> x;
    while (x > 0) { x /= 3; k++; }
    int *a = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        while (x > 0) { t = 0; t = x % 3; a[i] = t; x /= 3; }}
    for (int i = k; i < 0; i--) { cout << a[i]; }
    return 0;
    delete[]a;}
int main()
{x1 = perefod(x);
    return 0;}
```

Comment: Окакой "проблеме" идет речь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем именно массив? Раз выводить нужно - берите строку:

```
string perevod(int x)
{
    string s;
    while(x)
    {
        s = char('0'+x%3) + s;
        x /= 3;
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << perevod(n) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Вот это s = char('0'+x%3) + s можете объяснить, как работает?

Comment: Добавляем очередной символ (цифру превращаем в соответствующий символ) к строке спереди.

Comment: я искал ,как сделать из числа строку,но не нашёл.Хотя изначально была идея посимвольно разобрать.Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Ну, если вопрос решен - помечайте ответ как принятый (птица слева).

Comment: Очередной анонимный минус - ну так покажите ошибку в моем ответе, в чем проблема? :)

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста,может статья есть по таким магическим действиям или это опыт уже,просто первый раз вижу char('0'+x%3).

Comment: Да никакой магии. Имеем цифры - 0 1 2 3... и символы '0' '1' '2' '3' ... Цифра N - как число - отстоит от цифры как числа 0 на расстояние N. Но на столько же и символ цифры N отстоит от символа '0' - вот мы, чтоб получить символ для цифры N, "сдвигаемся" от цифры '0' на N: `'0'+N`. ну, а явное преобразование в `char` - потому что иначе `string` не понимает, что мы от него хотим.

Comment: @Harry, все какраз правильно. кто то ничего не понел

Comment: @Александр Веммон,  s = char('0'+x%3) + s   то же самое, что и    s.insert(s.begin(), '0'+x%3);

Answer (score 0):

После    `while (x > 0) { x /= 3; k++; }`   `x==0`, и вся остальная часть функции ничего не будет делать, тем более что вы перед удалением уже возвращаете ноль( не понятно что вы пытались этим выразить), так что удаление массива тоже не произойдет.  Для этой функции ничего не нужно возвращать, раз вы вывод пытаетсь осуществлять прямо в функции. Ее нужно определять как  `void  perefod(int x)`. И можно выполнить в вашем стиле тоже, только по логике уже вами принятого ответа.